# What is the benefit (rep?) to someone who votes to close a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

What is the benefit (rep?) if any to someone who votes to close a question? Is that benefit still there at all if the vote is wrong?

Comment: In general, the benefit to the close voter is negative.  Like downvoting, many OP's cannot accept that their question is bad and lash out.  Close voting, however, is not anonymous, making curators an easier target for sundry malice.

Answer (score 14):

There isn't any benefit such as reputation or badges.

People vote to close questions without any sort of reward in order to keep the site clean and to remove questions that don't meet the requirements of the site - such as being off topic or too unclear to answer.

It's purely a volunteer activity, without any sort of reward or recognition for the effort of keeping the site running smoothly.

Comment: There are badges if you vote to close in some cases - e.g. in review queues Steward/Reviewer/Custodian - self deletion and some flag raising might count, But yes the main reason is the satisfaction of keeping the site clean. (Note that the rewards for review queses were significantly raised recently to increase their use)

Comment: @mmmmmm The rewards for *what*?